# MySQL bidirectional trigger

Tags: mysql

I have to do two triggers, first one, after insert in `test1` table, to insert in `test2` table another row. All right, the problem is that i have to do same trigger in reverse form, after insert row in `test2` table, insert new row on `test1`. I know that trigger can't insert in a table when a trigger is firing, but i need resolve this. I don't have a lot experience with triggers, i hope that this could be resolved.

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `ai_test1_test2` AFTER INSERT ON `test1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN INSERT INTO test2 (vtest2) VALUES (new.vtest1)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Bidirectional trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `ai_test2_test1` AFTER INSERT ON `test2` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN INSERT INTO test1 (vtest1) VALUES (new.vtest2)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks.

*Edit*:

The infinite loop can't be resolved. Triggers can't be bidirectional... I think that i must be use a PROCEDURE...

Comment: Nope, this cannot be resolved via triggers and there is a very good reason why: it would risk an endless loop (trigger1 inserts into table2, which triggers trigger2, which inserts into table1. This in turn triggers an insert into table2...). Better take care of this in application logic or in stored procedures.

Comment: thanks @Shadow, yes, the loop is the problem... :(, i thought that every trigger was a individual execution that can't call an another trigger action into first trigger action...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a posible solution for the problem:

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `ai_test1_test2` AFTER INSERT ON `test1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT vtest2 FROM test2 WHERE vtest2 = new.vtest1 ) THEN
    INSERT INTO test2 (vtest2) VALUES (new.vtest1)
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `ai_test2_test1` AFTER INSERT ON `test1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT vtest1 FROM test1 WHERE vtest1 = new.vtest2 ) THEN
    INSERT INTO test1 (vtest1) VALUES (new.vtest2)
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop can't be resolved. Triggers can't be bidirectional... I think that i must be use a `PROCEDURE`...

Comment: You didn't explain your *real* problem. This is a clear [example of XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you're using triggers as a solution to the real problem. Then, you realized you can't have triggers firing the way you want to because that creates an infinite loop. My suggestion to you would be to edit your question and explain *why* you wanted to use triggers in the first place. I'm sure that someone will give you a solution to your real problem.

Comment: I have to tables, a CRM table with products and ERP table with products...
When i add a product on the CRM, that must be duplicate on a ERP table. And reverse, when the product is created on a ERP table, the product must be create on a CRM table... thanks @Mjh

Comment: What Shadow suggested seems the easiest and fastest way to solve this problem - simply do it from within your application, this one will be a nightmare to implement via database. You can always create a stored procedure and check which table needs duplicated record, but I personally believe it would be easier to do it from within application. It's difficult to debug stored procedures, especially if you plan to hire additional programmers who are supposed to work on it sometime in the future. Keep application logic in application in this particular case. Having said that, I wish you good luck!

Comment: Yes, you are rigth @Mjh... but i need resolve this on MySQL. Thanks!